# What does "nailed down" mean in this context?

Tags: idioms

What does it mean?

> Really got that look nailed down.

Comment: "nailed down" == did it very well. Or that he succeeded, or did it like he was a professional, or did it perfectly, etc.

Comment: @F.E. Please post answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - There are many reasons people might want to leave a helpful comment, and not necessarily spend time writing a full-blown answer. Please stop leaving that response to helpful, valid comments.

Comment: Four close votes, but zero links to a dictionary. **Before a fifth person casts a close vote**, take this challenge: I'll show you a link to a dictionary; you tell me which of those three meanings coincide with the O.P.'s context: [Link to *nail down* in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nailed-down). *This is a fair question* (although it would have been better had the O.P. included a few definitions found on their own, with a comment along the lines of "None of these seem right.")

Answer (score 2):

Nailed down is a phrase similar to nailed it.

From [this site](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/nailed-it)

> "Nailed It is a phrase used to express success after achieving
>   something seemingly difficult with relative ease. Online, it is often
>   found as a caption on image macros or in sarcastic commentary
>   criticizing the quality of success, especially in response to attempts
>   at recreating recipes or craft projects."

The site also lists the origin, spread and a few notable examples.

Also, the [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nailed%20it) includes a similar definition.

Comment: So, it is sarcasm? Also what is "image macros" and what is "recipes of craft projects"?

Comment: And why he said not "The look nailed down" but "got nailed down"?

Comment: no, not always sarcasm. Sometimes it can express genuine astonishment at achieving something difficult. Image macro is a formal term for a meme - Image superimposed with funny text.

Comment: And why he said not "The look nailed down" but "got nailed down"? --> This is because of grammar. It may be an idiom but the grammar still needs to be correct. Hence it is written this way.